# Remove brackets link footer in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

I started using Mediawiki, I tried to add a link in the footer after I installed an extension. I used the following code, however, the link in the footer got brackets around it. How do I remove this? It shows:

```
⧼contact⧽
```

```
$wgHooks['SkinAddFooterLinks'][] = function( Skin $skin, string $key, array &$footerlinks ) {
    if ( $key === 'places' ) {
        $footerlinks['contact'] = Html::element( 'a',
            [
                'href' => 'https://www.example.org/wiki/Special:Contact',  // URL to "Special:Contact"
                'rel' => 'noreferrer noopener'  // not required, but recommended for security reasons
            ],
        $skin->msg( 'contactpage-label' )->text()
        );
    };
};
```

I want to remove the brackets around the link

Answer (score 0):

If the PHP code that you posted is correct, you should be seeing `⧼contactpage-label⧽`, not `⧼contact⧽`. It means that you have to create the message *MediaWiki:contactpage-label*. If you use message caching, you will have to update the cache.